# Change default "Create Document" label in DocumentGroup

Tags: swiftui, documentgroup

The SwiftUI DocumentGroup allows us to easily create a document-based application. I'm looking at customizing the DocumentGroup.

How can we change the label "Create Document"? Am I overlooking a modifier?
In my use-case the term "Document" is a bad name for what it actually is, and I want to make the UI clearer by setting it to something else.

[image]